# Powers that increase damage rolls, do they increase flat damage and automatic damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

As to the title, I am testing out a class and something occurred to me.  There is a power that gives a power bonus to damage rolls.  I know there are plenty of powers that do such things, but the part I never came across before until the test:

If I use magic missile as an example that has the effect do auto damage to the target, would the power bonus to damage rolls apply or would it not simply because that it says specifically do damage rolls and not flat damage by itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different ways extra damage applies. Either to the "Damage roll" or by adding to the damage done. If the power/item says it adds to the damage roll then it does not apply to powers like magic missile. If the power says it adds to the "damage" then it can be applied to magic missile and its compadres.

Another note per Simon's comment. If the power specifies the power must hit then it will not add on a power like magic missile that does damage on the effect line rather than the hit line. No matter if you roll the damage or not.